# C- stack variable disappearing between iterations

Tags: c, pointers, stack

Hi I am new to C and spent far too long trying to find this bug. Here is an example of what was happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct Garbage {
  int value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  struct Garbage* pointers[10];
  while (i < 10) {
    struct Garbage temp = { .value = i * 7 };
    pointers[i] = &temp;
    i++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("pointers[%d]->value %d\n", i, pointers[i]->value);
  }
}
```

Why does this print

```
pointers[:]->value: [63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, ]
```

I assume it is because on each iteration of the while loop, temp gets placed in the same position on the stack. But why would it do that? Why does C think that it can just destroy my variables?
Is there a name for what is going on here? I tried to find relevant information but was unable to. So if you tell me what this is called I'll be able to do some searching myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because you're saving a pointer to the same variable space (which technically goes out of scope at the end of the first loop) in the array.  If you want different results, you need to store the data in separately allocated space that does not vanish when the loop ends.  What you're doing invokes _undefined behaviour_ which is unconditionally a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually figured this out shortly after posting (and forgot that I had made this post) but I appreciate the responses and I hope someone else will come across this and find it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't allocate `temp` properly.

```
struct Garbage* pointers[10];
while (i < 10) {
    struct Garbage temp = { .value = i * 7 };
    pointers[i] = &temp;
    i++;
}
```

Once `struct Garbage temp` goes out of scope (or really once each iteration ends), you no longer have claim to any of the memory that your pointers point to. Accessing that memory is undefined behavior.

What's likely happening is the same stack space is being allocated for every `struct Garbage temp` created, so all your pointers probably point to the same memory address. You could verify that with `printf("%p\n", pointers[i])` (all of the pointers will be the same).

One way to fix this is to use `malloc`

```
struct Garbage* pointers[10];
while (i < 10) {
    pointers[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Garbage));
    pointers[i]->value = i * 7;
    i++;
}
```

Just remember to `free` all those pointers when you're done with them.